# Get a script to run at startup (linux)

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to get a simple script to run automatically at startup.  A friend told me to do this but it did not work.  Could someone take a look to see what it is missing?

*(Also I am brand new to linux, so this is pretty foreign to me)

Here is what I was told to do:

In terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/obabp.sh
```

Then enter this text:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /home/pi/gits/RPi-OBABP/src/obabp.py
```

save file and then

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/obabp.sh
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 3):

Use cron. Add this to your crontab:

```
@reboot path to script
```

Click here for details: [Linux Crontab: 15 Awesome Cron Job Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: I literally just figured it out by putting it in the startup sequence but this method would have been much easier! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can execute/start scripts/daemons during boot by configuring `/etc/rc.local`. So theoretically, you can start the daemons in sequential order, by listing them in `/etc/rc.local`. See if the following works for your situation.

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/path/to/bash
/etc/init.d/mpd start
/etc/init.d/daemon1 start
/etc/init.d/daemon2 start
/etc/init.d/your/script/that/depends/on/daemons
```

Comment: I think your on the right track.  However my version of Linux doesn't have /etc/rc.local folder, I have rc0.d through rc6.d and I have tried changing the boot order there, if I am doing it correctly that is.  I followed these instructions: http://www.ehow.com/how_6162954_change-start-order-processes-linux.html

Comment: That being said, it still didn't work, so I'm hoping a made a mistake somewhere

Comment: What distro are you using? Also, do you have /etc/init.d/rc.local?

Comment: No i don't have that either.  I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi mini computer, so its running a version of Debian (I think) called Raspbian

Comment: OK so I renamed the file to change the sequence but I need to update it.  And here is my rookie-ness showing, can someone look at this and tell me what I'm supose to do? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwpezgph736gna4/2012-12-17%2001.02.06.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Since sudo usually prompts you for a password, I don't think you can really do this. I don't know exactly what your script is doing, but I'm assuming that you shouldn't need to be root to run it. Try removing "sudo" from the line "sudo python /home/pi/gits/RPi-OBABP/src/obabp.py" If that works, I'll help you tidy this up a bit more.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried that, but the script does actually need to be run with sudo.  Its on a little Raspberry Pi computer and it has something to do with the GPIO connector that needs sudo I guess. It won't let me run the script without using it

Comment: I'm betting something needs to be done to make the script active, perhaps something like `sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d obabp.sh defaults`

Comment: @GregA.Woods Now we are getting somewhere. When I watch the boot process it tries to start the script but comes up with errors.  Would you know why?  the script runs perfectly when I start it in the terminal

Comment: perhaps if you post the errors you see -- even better add in the missing step that got you this far into your question, then add the errors you see there too.

Comment: @GregA.Woods here is a screen picture of the errors. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kdz2zzzdu6yr7k/2012-12-16%2023.28.44.jpg

Comment: Not sure if this could effect it but the python script it starts links to another python script to run... does that make sense? I could email you if that is easier. Mine is dangraves25@gmail.com

Comment: What is the script trying to connect to? Perhaps you need to start a service prior to running your script?

Comment: @fbynite Good point, I never thought of that.  It is a one button audiobook player so I use a few other programs since its playing audio. (mpd, mpc, pyudev, python-mpd) How could i make it be the very last thing to start at boot?

Comment: Depending on if you are using Upstart or not scripts are ordered. If you are using Ubuntu chances are that you are using upstart and you can order your script after mpd by adding a number infront of it e.g. 99obabp.sh If you are not using Upstart you can see in which /etc/rc*.d mpd starts and put your script in a higher run level.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to create a start script into

```
/etc/rcS.d/
```

I believe the scripts within the rcS.d starting 'S' are executed in the sequential order.

Comment: I don't have that directory.  I have rc0.d thru rc6.d and I found out my OS defult boots with rc2.d so i tried changing the order but it doesn't seem to be working